# DirectX11 / DXTK - how to draw a simple line?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

i'm just starting with DirectX and i cant figure out how to draw a simple line. I tried the following but it doesnt seem to work:

**Creation of device and swapchain:**

```
D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
    nullptr,                            
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,           
    nullptr,                            
    D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED, 
    nullptr,                            
    0,                                  
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &swapChainDesc,
    &this->SwapChain,
    &this->Device,
    nullptr,
    &this->DeviceContext);
```

**Initialization of BasicEffect and PrimitiveBatch:**

```
// PrimitiveBatch
this->Batch.reset(new PrimitiveBatch<VertexPositionColor>(this->DeviceContext));

// BasicEffect
this->Effect.reset(new BasicEffect(this->Device));
this->Effect->SetVertexColorEnabled(true);

void const* shaderByteCode;
size_t byteCodeLength;

this->Effect->GetVertexShaderBytecode(&shaderByteCode, &byteCodeLength);

// Set InputLayout
this->Device->CreateInputLayout(
    VertexPositionColor::InputElements,
    VertexPositionColor::InputElementCount,
    shaderByteCode,
    byteCodeLength,
    &this->InputLayout);

this->Effect->SetProjection(DirectX::XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterRH(0.f, 800.f, 600.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f));
this->Effect->SetWorld(DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity());
this->Effect->SetView(DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity());
```

**Draw test function:**

```
this->Effect->Apply(this->DeviceContext);
this->DeviceContext->IASetInputLayout(this->InputLayout);

this->Batch->Begin();

const XMVECTORF32 s1 = { 10.f, 50.f, 1.f };
const XMVECTORF32 s2 = { 20.f, 200.f, 1.f };

VertexPositionColor v1(s1, Colors::Green);
VertexPositionColor v2(s2, Colors::Green);

this->Batch->DrawLine(v1, v2);

this->Batch->End();
```

**Where DrawLine is called:**

```
this->DeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(this->RenderTargetView, Colors::Black);

// Trying to DrawLine
this->DrawLine(); // <- where Batch->DrawLine is executed**

this->SwapChain->Present(0, 0);
```

I followed this example -> https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PrimitiveBatch&referringTitle=Home but i'm not experienced enough to know what else do i need for the line to be drawn.

Comment: Are you calling `IDXGISwapChain::Present()`. The line you are drawing is in 3D so you will also need to set up a view and projection matrix. Did you set an orthographic projection matrix as in the example?

Comment: i extended the code part. Should i add the rest?

Comment: Did you create a swap chain when you initialized your D3D device and do you call `Present()` on it after `this->Batch->End()`?

Comment: First off, thank you for your time megadan! Second: could it be because of the projection?

Comment: OK, looks like the projection was the problem. I passed it directly to the set method which caused the line not to be drawn. Now it seems like its working. I'm still getting into DX (not my world yet).